# Migrating and consolidating database from SQL Server 2000 into Existing SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I’d like to know what should I prepare and pay special attention to in migrating and consolidating the SQL Server 2000 database into SQL Server 2005 ?
From what I can think of now is that manual Backup and restore is the way to go here.

Any kind of help and suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally use the backup and restore method, set the compatibility level to SQL 2005, and run DBCC UPDATEUSAGE (0);

Comment: ah.. that does make sense Joe. many thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 2):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966519.aspx